# How to get Azure ActiveDirectory token for .Net Core Web Api Default Template?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, asp-net-core-spa-services

I have created the default template with visual studio 2019 for .net core web api.  I chose to use the default wizard authentication:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
            services.AddControllers();
```

I've tried to generate the token using Postman (which gives me a token, but return unauthorized).

What steps am I missing?

At this step all I want to do is call an authorized controller via postman.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the token you generated with Postman (using https://jwt.ms or similar) and see whether it's audience (aud claim) is as exactly the same as what's in your AzureAD section of appSettings.json (it may be called ApplicationId there). There could be other claims that are failing validation (particularly issuer) and causing unauthorized return but I assume your Postman is using same directory as your API. Audience is the most common cause of error.